# COM SAFEARRAY memory from C++ to VBA

Tags: c++, vba, com

I would like to create a SAFEARRAY of user defined type (UDT) in an UDT.
I have one structure Data which contains the S structure. S is composed with S1 and S2.

I need to create in c++ the array S of my Data object with the COM function.

When I call my function from the VBA to create the array, the VBA crashes at the end of the function.
If I remove s7 from S, it works perfectly.

I aligned my struct with 4 bytes.

I don't find any help on this problem on the web.

You can see the code here:

- VBA code:

  ```
  #If VBA7 Then
      Private Declare PtrSafe Function Cpp_Test2 Lib "MYLIB.dll" (i As Data) As Long
  #Else
      Private Declare Function Cpp_Test2 Lib "MYLIB.dll" (i As Data) As Long
  #End If

  Public Type S1
      d1 As Double
      S1 As String
      S2 As String
      d2 As Double
      d3 As Double
      i1 As Long
      i2 As Long
      d4 As Double
      d5 As Double
      s3 As String
      s4 As String
      s5 As String
      s6 As String
      d6 As Double
      d7 As Double
      d8 As Double
      s7 As String
  End Type

  Type S2
      n As Long
      x() As Double
      y() As Double
  End Type

  Type S
      ms1 As S1
      ms2 As S2
  End Type

  Type Data
      d As Double
      n As Long
      ms() As S
  End Type

  Sub TestFunction()
      Dim d As Data
      MsgBox Cpp_Test2(d)
      Stop
  End Sub
  ```
- C++ code:
- idl file:

  ```
      typedef [uuid(C8166034-DF8D-460A-B38E-F9342694AABA)] struct S1
      {
          double d1;
          BSTR s1;
          BSTR s2;
          double d2;
          double d3;
          int i1;
          int i2;
          double d4;
          double d5;
          BSTR s3; 
          BSTR s4; 
          BSTR s5; 
          BSTR s6;
          double d6;
          double d7;
          double d8;
          BSTR s7;
      } S1;

      typedef [uuid(539CF724-616E-46B6-8990-AD14F8190737)] struct S2
      {
          int n;
          SAFEARRAY(double) x; //dbl
          SAFEARRAY(double) y; //dbl
      } S2;

      typedef [uuid(0B689485-F347-4414-BF86-07926AC2526C)] struct S
      {
          S1 s1;
          S2 s2;
      } S;
  ```
- cpp file:

  ```
  const IID IID_S = { 0x0B689485, 0xF347,     0x4414{0xBF,0x86,0x07,0x92,0x6A,0xC2,0x52,0x6C
                                        }
  };

  struct Data
  {
      double d;
      int n;
      SAFEARRAY *S;
  };

  __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall  Cpp_Test2(Data *d)
  {
      SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
      rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;
      rgsabound[0].cElements = 5;
      IRecordInfo* pRecInfo = NULL;
      HRESULT hr = GetRecordInfoFromGuids(LIBID_MYLIB, 9, 9, 0, IID_S, &pRecInfo);

      if (pRecInfo)
      {
          d->S = SafeArrayCreateEx(VT_RECORD, 1, rgsabound, pRecInfo);
          return 1;
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.
I have already used SafeArrayCreateEx without problem but here it seems there a memory problem.

Comment: Are you using 64 or 32 bit office?

Comment: I use a 32 bit office.

Comment: Ugh, nice job minimizing the problem.  Never declare COM types twice, your VBA code must use the type library you created from your IDL so there can never be a mismatch.  Use the __uuidof keyword to avoid declaring guids twice.

Comment: I corrected the declaration of types but the problem is still here.

Comment: I seem to recall reading somewhere that VB uses 8-byte alignment , while C++ uses 4-byte alignment by default. So the two do not agree on how to pack structures together in an array. Try adding a dummy Long member at the end of the structure, to pad it to a multiple of 8 bytes.

Comment: It's work fine if I declare structure only in C++.
But I need to declare the structure on VBA and on C++ because we cannot take the COM structure on OS X :(
And now, when I have the both declaration, it's crashed when I redim x of S2 on VBA and it's work fine if I don't redim.
Do you have any idea why?
I find any solution on the web...